# Laravel Application Displays List of Files Instead of "Hello Page"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I've just started working with Laravel 5, but I've been unable to show the classic Hello page yet; I only see a listing of my application files.

I've tried to change my .htaccess file, clear my cache, create a new app, but to no avail. I know PHP works fine on my server, it's only this one Laravel application that can't seem to handle it.  This seems like I'm missing some obvious thing, but I don't know enough to know what I should be asking.

Here's a screenshot to demonstrate what I see:

[image]

and here's the command I used to created the app

```
 $ laravel new m6g
```

I'm working on a Mac with the stock apache2 (not set with mamp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, technically Laravel isn't 'not interpreting PHP' Laravel doesnt interprent PHP, the PHP engine interprets PHP.

You have apache configured to serve things only from 127.0.0.1/localhost and you're using apache to browse folders on your machine at the moment.

Apache should be configured (possibly with a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)) to point to /m6g/public. At which point apache will see your index.php file and put it through PHP.

Comment: thx it s now working after setting up some virtualhost, however, I cannot access anymore to the DocumentRoot level, its automatically redirected towards the m6g app...

Comment: You can set up multiple virtualhosts. Just create another one thats pointed at the root if you'd like.

Comment: i am using a shared hosting can not configure virtual host, is there any other way aroung ???

Comment: @MohdSamganKhan get better hosting

Comment: @castis thanks for the suggestion, but found a better solution.
can be done by making some change in the .htaccess file in root. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to mount your app from the terminal?

First, go to the folder on the terminal using cd and

Then run the following command:

```
php artisan serve
```

then you will be able to access your app from http://localhost:8888

Comment: yes it works but only for development purpose, thx for showing this command though

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue on my project by increasing privileges on storage directory. The following command should fix your problem.

```
chmod 777 -R storage
```

Comment: This will open your storage folder for public access which is itself a security risk.